# sort list of start date and end date in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have start date and end date. how to sort it.
Here is my attempt but it works only for one date list

```
String sorted_date = "";
  String from_date="";
  List<String> listDates = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < leaveTransactionDetail.size(); i++) {
  if (leaveTransactionDetail.get(i).get("from_date").toString().trim().equals("0000-00-00")) {
      sorted_date = leaveTransactionDetail.get(i).get("to_date").toString().trim();

        } else {
          sorted_date = leaveTransactionDetail.get(i).get("from_date").toString().trim();
       
          }
          listDates.add(sorted_date);
    }
          Collections.sort(listDates);

          out.println("After sorting: " + listDates);
```

Here is my table

[image]

I want output dates are in sorted order

[image]

Comment: What is the actual output ? What's wrong in your code ?

Comment: Do you *have* to maintain the dates as strings? In general, working with time information is much easier if you use time-specific types, e.g. LocalDate. (That said, ISO-8601 dates are already sortable... as Elikill58 says, what's going wrong at the moment?)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are supposed to sort them independently from each other or are they supposed to be sorted in alternating order? If the latter is the cause you might wanna combine the two into one list and split them afterwards

Answer (score 1):

For me, you have to use a new object.

```java
public class DateStartEnd implements Comparable {
        public String start, end;

        public DateStartEnd(String start, String end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
        
        public String getStart() {
            return start;
        }
        
        public String getEnd() {
            return end;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Start:" + start + ",End:" + end; // here it's just to check result, such as I test with different year, it's "showable" for me
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) { // method from comparable interface
            if(!(o instanceof DateStartEnd))
                return 0; // if it's not good object type
            DateStartEnd other = (DateStartEnd) o; // cast to current one
            return getStart().compareTo(other.getEnd()); // compare date between current and next
        }
}
```

Then now we create own object and compare them :

```java
List<DateStartEnd> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < leaveTransactionDetail.size(); i++) {
   // get from and to dates
   String fromDate = leaveTransactionDetail.get(i).get("from_date").toString().trim();
   String toDate = leaveTransactionDetail.get(i).get("to_date").toString().trim();
   dates.add(new DateStartEnd(fromDate, toDate)); // add to all dates
}

Collections.sort(dates); // this will use the compare method, define in the object thanks to "Comparable" interface

System.out.println("After sorting: " + dates); // print result
```

Comment: no still it sorts only one date list...i have to show start date and end date in sorted order together.

Comment: Ok but can you give example in your main post of input/output ? Because i don't know how we can sort  2 two at the same time, for me you will have to make a new object

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I just edit my answer, it works for me

Comment: it shows result as After sorting: [Start:-1898,End:121, Start:121,End:121, Start:121,End:121, Start:121,End:121, Start:121,End:121, Start:121,End:121, Start:121,End:-1898]

Comment: it's because of the `toString()` method of `DateStartEnd`, you can edit it. Also, I will try to keep string, maybe it will be better for you (after sorting)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235380/discussion-between-elikill58-and-sanju-verma).

Comment: Finally, does this answer to your question ?

Comment: No sir. i did it by mysql query.